# How to add an onchange listener to a checkbox on Yii2 to submit form when changed

Tags: checkbox, yii2

I want to submit the search form whenever I check or uncheck the checkboxes. I've got the following code but can't make it work... it's quite simple I guess but can't get around it!

```
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'pets_allowed')->checkbox(['options'=>['onchange'=>'"this.form.submit();}"']]); ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why you have a } after(); ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the double quotes `"` from the expression `'"this.form.submit();}"'` and the `}`. Then you need to pass the array of options not the keyword `options`, see the API Doc for [checkbox](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkbox()-detail)

so it should be

```
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'pets_allowed')->checkbox(['onchange' => 'this.form.submit()']); ?>
```

But the problem in the above script is that is would submit the form even if you uncheck it, so a better way should be that you check the state of the checkbox. i would use jquery and [heredoc](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/php/php-here-document-heredoc-syntax-examples) like below so that you can have readability in your code and easy editing.

```
<?php 

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$js = <<<JS
    $("#pets_allowed").on('change',function(){

        // to submit only if the checkbox is checked otherwise 
        // you can remove the check and just use the submit statement
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }

    });
JS;

    $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>

<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'pets_allowed')->checkbox(['id'=>'pets_allowed']); ?> 

<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

Comment: Actually I want to submit if I check or un-check, as a sort of real-time filter. But it's still not working :/

Comment: its pretty straight forward and i have added the code after testing it, but its hard to get when you say it is not working, do you get any errors on console? add your complete view after the updated code @EricLehmann

Comment: Hi Muhammad, you're right, I should have provided more information. I'm checking at the console in Chrome with verbose activated but can't identify any errors or warnings related to the problem. Indeed it should be quite straight forward, that's why I don't understand why it doesnt work...
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'pets_allowed')->checkbox(['onchange' => 'this.form.submit()']); ?> 
                                </div>

Comment: you can use the suggested second option and just remove the check in the javascript and use only the `submit` statement as pointed out in the code comments @EricLehmann